# Passport validity for a US & Israel dual-citizen returning to the US

Tags: passports, us-citizens

We are Israeli citizens residing in the US on work visas. Our daughter is a citizen of both the US and Israel. We are travelling from the US to Israel and back soon. Since our daughter is a dual-citizen she needs an Israeli passport to enter/exit Israel and a US passport to enter/exit the US.

Should we expect any issues if her US passport expires in less than 6 months at the time of travel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She should be fine.

She should check in for her US > Israel flight using her Israeli passport, and check in using her US passport for the Israel > US flight.

[Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) (the IATA database used by airlines to ascertain if a passenger's documentation is sufficient) states her US passport must be valid on arrival:

> National USA (US)               /Destination USA (US)
>
> USA (US)
>
> Passport required.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     nationals of USA must be valid on arrival.